# Issue with GridSearch CV for Random Forest: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite:

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv, user-warning

I am training to tune parameters for my random forest. I am using Grid Search CV.

Here is my parameter grid.

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42)

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100,200,300],
     'max_depth': np.arange(3,8,1),
     'max_features': ['auto'],
     'min_samples_leaf': [0.01,0.02],
     'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
     'bootstrap': [True]
}
```

Here is my attempt to do grid search

```
rs = GridSearchCV(rf,
                  return_train_score=True, 
                  param_grid=param_grid, 
                  scoring="r2",
                  cv=5, verbose = 2, n_jobs = -1)
```

When I run this I get this user warning: *UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite:*

When I check

```
rs.cv_results_
```

All the split test scores are nan. All the data types are numeric and I have tried this with multiple scoring metrics. However, the gridsearch still returns best estimator. What is going on here?

Comment: Set `error_score='raise'` in `GridSearchCV` and report your output.